# Python pde solution using fipy gives value error

Tags: python, valueerror, pde, fipy

I am trying to solve a pde using the fipy package in python. The code that I have written for the same has been attached.

```
!pip install fipy
from fipy import *
mesh= Grid2D(nx=0.001,dx=100,ny=0.0005,dy=100)
phil=CellVariable(name='Sol variable',mesh=mesh)
phil.constrain(0,mesh.facesBottom)
phil.constrain(1,mesh.facesTop)
n=1.7*10**(-6)*((0.026*numerix.exp(phil/0.026)+phil-0.026)+2.25*10**(-10)*(0.026*numerix.exp(phil/0.026)-phil-0.026))**(0.5)
eq=(PowerLawConvectionTerm(coeff=(0.,1.))+ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=n))
eq.solve(var=phil)
```

When I try to run the code, I get an error in the last line: k exceeds matrix dimensions.
 Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious issue with the above code is that `dx` and `nx` are mixed up. `dx` is the mesh spacing so is a float while `nx` are the number of mesh cells, which is an int. So, the third line should be,

```
mesh= Grid2D(dx=0.001,nx=100,dy=0.0005,ny=100)
```

That at least makes the problem run without an error. However the solution isn't very interesting as the source term and the initial condition appear to be zero everywhere so the result is zero everywhere.

It's also worth considering the following

- FiPy isn't really designed for hyperbolic problems, which require high order discretizations to solve accurately. It will solve, but may not be as accurate (it might be ok in equilibrium).
- The source term is non-linear so will require many iterations to reach a solution.
- It's a good idea to have a transient term in this type of equation and iterate towards equilibrium.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It was indeed an error with the syntax which I messed up. But my source term is not 0. The coefficient of the source term is 'n' which has been defined and the source term is also further dependent on the variable 'phil'. I am getting zero soln everywhere which should not be the case. And initial condition can be 0. I don't understand why you said that the source term is 0. And I don't actually have a transient term in the equation.

Comment: And could you please suggest me how to incorporate such variable dependent source terms in Fipy?

Comment: `phil` is initially zero. Your source is zero because an `ImplicitSourceTerm` represents `coeff * var`. Your equation is $\nabla\cdot(\phi \vec{v}) + n \phi == 0$

Comment: Well, at least when I printed out the variable "n" is just showed lost of zeros and did a max and min on it. It may have numerically rounded to zero since it was so small.

Comment: Variable dependent source terms need to be linearlized, which you've done already with ImplicitSourceTerm. You have many choices when linearizing though. Using a Taylor expansion is the best way to do this in general.

Comment: Adding a TransientTerm doesn't change your equation if you evolve the equation to equilibrium. It's a way to stabilize the evolution to equilibrium.